# Can I know whether Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn logged in a user or created an account?

Tags: facebook, parse-platform

I'm using `Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn`, passing a facebook authentication token, for both logging in and signing up to my application. Is there a way to check if the function logged a user in or signed them up? I'd like to direct them to onboarding once they have signed up.

Comment: Do you have a server-side store of users? You could check that when a user logs in to see if they're new/returning? I don't think it's possible to determine from calling that method if it was a new or existing user

Comment: You're right, it isn't possible. I didn't want to store a flag for it either, so I went with a hacky way of checking if the created at date was a relatively small time ago.